# Yii2: добавить timestamp к js, подключенному через registerJsFile()

Tags: php, javascript, css, yii2

Я знаю, что в yii2 можно добавлять timestamp к подключаемым js/css, если в AssetManager указать `'appendTimestamp' => true`.

Но это работает только для тех js/css, которые публикуются через `sourcePath` в AssetBundle.

Как автоматически добавить timestamp к js, опубликованному через `registerJsFile()`?

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось сделать это следующим образом.

Находясь в шаблоне, вместо `$this->registerJsFile($file)` нужно написать следующее:

```
$file = '/js/page.js';
$asset = new \yii\web\AssetBundle([
    'js' => [ltrim($file, '/')],
    'basePath' => '@webroot',
    'baseUrl' => '/'
]);
$this->getAssetManager()->bundles[$file] = $asset;
$this->registerAssetBundle($file);
```

То есть, вместо `registerJsFile()` мы создаем новый AssetBundle прямо в шаблоне и регистрируем его.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать переписать класс AppAsset, если вы его конечно используете:

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [];

    public static $extra_js = [];
    public static $extra_depends = [];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        foreach(self::$extra_depends as $d) $this->depends[] = $d;
        foreach(self::$extra_js as $js) $this->js[] = $js;
    }

    public static function addJs($js)
    {
        self::$extra_js[] = $js;
    }

    public static function addDepends($depends)
    {
        if (!is_array($depends)) $depends = [$depends];

        foreach($depends as $el) {
            self::$extra_depends[] = $el;
        }    
    }    

}
```

А потом во view файле или в любом другом месте до вызова AppAsset::register($this)
Просто сделать что-то подобное:

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
//эта часть нужна, если хотите, чтобы выше вашего файла был jquery-ui
AppAsset::addDepends([\yii\jui\JuiAsset::className()]); 
//а это уже ваш файл
AppAsset::addJs('js/my.js');
```

Comment: Тоже вариант, спасибо. Правда в итоге я пришел к тому, что все подключамые файлы я делаю AssetBundle'ами, а не включаю их отдельными файлами в шаблоне. Иначе рано или поздно все равно вылезают проблемы либо с зависимостью, либо с тесной связностью.